# PHP what is the best approach to using XML? Need to create and parse XML responses

Tags: php, xml

What are the recommended libraries for XML in PHP? Advantages? Looking to create/send/parse XML. Needs to support High Volume (Millions of calls per day)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP supports a number of [XML libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php).

If memory is an issue, for instance due to large files, use an [Event-based parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) over a [tree-based](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) one.[Tree-based](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) parsers must fully load the file into memory in order to parse the XML. [Event-based parsers](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.xmlreader.php) do not need to load the entire file into memory to begin parsing.

<s>See this article about [what's new with XML in PHP5](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1713#Heading6) and [a discussion of their pros and cons](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2387).</s>

You might also reconsider where you store the data, since filesystem might be too slow for *millions of calls*. How about [Xindice](http://xml.apache.org/xindice/)?

Comment: memory is not an issue but performance is what I'm looking for.

Comment: The data is parsed then directly stored in Oracle DB. It more of a request/post xml functionality

Comment: Sounds like Pull Parsing. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-pullparsingphp.html in which case XmlReader should be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleXml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) is by far the easiest! For any of the missing features in SimpleXml you can try [bXml](http://code.google.com/p/blibrary/source/browse/trunk/classes/bXml.class.inc), a warper library I wrote.

Comment: Needs to support High Volume (Millions of calls per day)

Comment: The data is parsed then directly stored in Oracle DB. It more of a request/post xml functionality instead of parsing a file, would this still be suggested to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you want use PHP intern XML Parser there are

[**XPATH**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp)
[**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/de/book.dom.php)
[**SimpleXml**](http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php)

Or If you want to use a XML Parser for PHP i can recommend [**Simplepie**](http://simplepie.org)

there are a lot but Simplepie is one of the Best.

Here is a Simple overview of how you could use it.

```
<?php
require_once('simplepie.inc');

$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://simplepie.org/blog/feed/');
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();
?>

<h1><a href="<?php echo $feed->get_permalink(); ?>">
<?php echo $feed->get_title(); ?></a></h1>
<p><?php echo $feed->get_description(); ?></p>

<?php foreach ($feed->get_items(0, 5) as $item): ?>

<h2 class="title"><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>">
<?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php echo $item->get_description(); ?>
<p>
<small>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?>
</small></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I'm not working with a DOM, more of a xml request/post functionality