# Split XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a merged xml with a root element and multiple item child elements.
Something like this

```
 <root>
  <item>test1</item>
  <item>test2</item>
 </root>
```

What I want is an easy way to parse the xml and create an array of xml strings from the items.

```
$arrXml[0] = '<item>test1</item>';
$arrXml[1] = '<item>test2</item>';
```

I'm looking for an elegant solution not any solution.

Comment: I don't understand how this is relevant ? I have a particular task with this particular solution. I don't thing the big picture can be changed. I believe I was clear enough in the requirements.

Comment: @user this simply sounds like a really dumb idea.

Comment: I can't believe you down vote me for not sharing a bigger picture even if you have experience in development. What I ask for is clear and I don't need a moral lesson. Also if you really need to know a 3th party is sending a big xml file. I need to parse the file and send each client the piece it needs also as an xml.

Comment: will the elements start and end on the same line? Also, from your bigger picture I'd say this approach is better solved with XSLT or at least without converting to an array. I mean, if you need to send XML back, why tranform to an array? Just pick the parts you need and send them. Btw, good Pekka asked.

Comment: @user The reason why I'm asking for the bigger picture is that using  string parsing for this is complicated to implement, and likely to invite a shitload of trouble, e.g. with nested structures. Have you considered using native XML functions for the whole process instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP what is the best approach to using XML? Need to create and parse XML responses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060346/php-what-is-the-best-approach-to-using-xml-need-to-create-and-parse-xml-response)

Comment: I edited the question to be able to remove my downvote. I still think it's unwise to do with arrays.

Comment: I need to split XML too. Trasforming XMLs is a common task in system integration platforms, like ESB. danip has asked a good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, like already mentioned in the comments to your question **I am not convinced this is really what you should be doing**, but since I cant stand SimpleXml and dont want people to think it's the only way, here is how to do it

**with `DOM`:**

```
$arrXml = array();
$dom    = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'item' ) as $item ) {
    $arrXml[] = $dom->saveXML( $item );
}
print_r( $arrXml );
```

---

**with `XMLReader`:**

```
$arrXml = array();
$reader = new XmlReader;
$reader->xml( $xml );
while( $reader->read() ) {
    if( $reader->localName === 'item' && $reader->nodeType === 1 ) {
        $arrXml[] = $reader->readOuterXml();
    }
}
print_r( $arrXml );
```

---

**and `XMLParser*`:**

```
xml_parse_into_struct(xml_parser_create(), $xml, $nodes);
$xmlArr = array();
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    if($node['tag'] === 'ITEM') {
        $arrXml[] = "<item>{$node['value']}</item>";
    }
}
print_r($arrXml);
```

<sup>* this can also be done via callbacks triggered when an ITEM element is encountered. Would take more code, but is pretty flexible.</sup>

**Note that all of the above might need some tweaking depending on your real XML.**

---

Given that the XML in your question (which is likely only an example) is dirt simple and well defined, you can also use `explode()`:

```
$arrXml = array_map( 'trim',
    array_filter(
        explode( PHP_EOL, $xml ),
        function( $line ) { return substr( $line, 0, 6 ) === '<item>'; }
));
print_r( $arrXml );
```

or a Regex (read disclaimer below)

```
preg_match_all('#<item>.*</item>#', $xml, $arrXml);
print_r($arrXml[0]);
```

**Disclaimer** Now, just to make sure you are not starting to parse XML with Regex or Explode on a regular basis: The last two approaches are only feasible if your markup is really that clearly defined as you show it.

Comment: You have not mentioned SimpleXmlElement, it can to xpath lookups. But according to my experience it's asXml() method does not handle namespaces well.

Answer (score 2):

There are some nice code examples in the comments of [SimpleXml manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). 
I am sure you can make something work from  `objectsIntoArray()` sample.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)?

For example:

```
$string = "
 <root>
  <item>test1</item>
  <item>test2</item>
 </root>
";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

Comment: This won't give him what he's asking for. That said, I'm not sure whether what he's asking for is a good idea

Comment: @Pekka - yep i know but he wants an elegant solution for parsing XML and simpleXML is just that (imo). Too much margin for error otherwise

Comment: This are the first steps , I agree..but the rest?