# Split XML nodes into php array

Tags: php, xml, split

I'm trying to split an XML string, like this:

```
<root>
  <item attr='test'>test1</item>
  <anotherItem>test2</anotherItem>
  <item3><t>Title</t><foo></foo></item3>
</root>
```

I want the array to look like:

```
$arrXml[0] = "<item attr='test'>test1</item>";
$arrXml[1] = "<anotherItem>test2</anotherItem>";
$arrXml[2] = "<item3><t>Title</t><foo></foo></item3>";
```

I already looked at the solutions in [Split XML in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022085/split-xml-in-php) but they only work for an XML document with only "item" nodes.

I've tried using XmlReader but after I use read(), how can I get the current node including its own xml with attributes? readOuterXml() doesn't seem to work and only outputs the inner value.

The xml doesn't contain \n so I can't use explode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SimpleXML:

```
$root = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$arrXml = array();

foreach($root as $child)
    $arrXml[] = $child->asXml();
```

Comment: When I run this code with: "<root><node attr='test'>123</node><node2><t>2</t></node2></root>" 
I get this: ["123<\/node>","2<\/t><\/node2>"], so without the first <node>?

Comment: @Anorionil When you output xml in browser don't forget about `htmlspecialchars` because xml nodes will be treated as HTML code...

Comment: Ahh thank you! It was working all along, I just didn't see it :/ Dumb :(

Answer (score 0):

based on your wished output what you are trying to do is parse string not XML string.
you can use regex or simply just explode.

something like:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
$arrXml = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if ($line == '<root>' || $line == '</root>') {
        continue;
    }
    $arrXml[] = $line;
}
```

Comment: There's no \n between the different lines I'm afraid. I added the line breaks just to make my example a bit more readable.

Comment: well than you should have mentioned that in your question :)