# Create output XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

How do I create this type of XML output using PHP?

```
<Root>
 <base>  rushi </base>
 <base> stack </base>
 <base> overflow </base>
<root>
```

Comment: you add a `?>` tag and just write it down. Please be more specific what kind of solution you are looking for. On a sidenote, your XML is invalid. The root node is not closed. XML is case-sensitive.

Comment: related and possible duplicate: [What is the best approach to using XML in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060346/php-what-is-the-best-approach-to-using-xml-need-to-create-and-parse-xml-response)

Comment: *(reference)* http://de.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at:

- [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)
- [Introducing SimpleXML in PHP 5](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Introducing-SimpleXML-in-PHP-5/)
- [Read and write XML with PHP](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=14165)

Answer (score 3):

Here is line by line code..Hope this will help you

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html

Answer (score 2):

```
$employees = array(
    '0'=> array(
         'name' =>'abin',
          'age' => '23',
      ),
    '1' => array(
        'name' => 'savin',
        'age'  => '24',
    )
);
//$file = fopen('file.xml','w');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<employees></employees>');
foreach($employees as $employ):
$xml->addChild('name',$employ['name']);
$xml->addChild('age',$employ['age']);
endforeach;
file_put_contents('file.xml',$xml->saveXML());
```

Comment: This line makes the trickfile_put_contents('file.xml',$xml->saveXML());