# turning on the dom_xml functionality on php 5

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I am trying to implement an store locator using php and mysql and google maps
I have gone through this article "https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 "
it says **"Check your configuration or try initializing a domxml_new_doc() to determine if your server's PHP has dom_xml functionality on.**"
But apparantly mine is not on because it is giving me this error :
"**Fatal error: Call to undefined function domxml_new_doc() in C:\wamp\www\StoreLocator\phpsqlajax_genxml.php on line 5**"
I am using php 5, and I am not sure how I can turn it on.
Please help me with your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4753171/2110460) might help answer your problems.

Are you sure you want to go down the XML route and not the JSON one?