# php generating xml adding text inside foreach loop

Tags: php, xml, string, loops, foreach

I want to generate a dynamic xml to send to a webservice.
I have a php foreach loop inside the xml.
But I can't get the syntax right.

I need the string to look like this -

```
<?xml version=1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
<inventoryUpdateRequest version="1.0">
<action name="bookupdate">
</action>
<SiteNameList>
<SiteName>
<vendorBookID>123456</vendorBookID>
</SiteName>
<SiteName>
<vendorBookID>788901</vendorBookID>
</SiteName>
</SiteNameList>
</inventoryUpdateRequest>

The <SiteName>...</SiteName> is looped for each value found.
```

My code so far is this -

```
<?php 
$xml =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
<inventoryUpdateRequest version="1.0">
<action name="bookupdate">
</action>
<SiteNameList>
'.
$ids_orderlineitem_portal_rownum = 1;
foreach($ids_row['order_line_item::bookID'] as  $ids_orderlineitem_portal_row=>$ids_orderlineitem_portal)
{
.'
<SiteName>
<vendorBookID>
'.$ids_row['order_line_item::bookID'][$ids_orderlineitem_portal_row].'
</vendorBookID>
</SiteName>
'.if($ids_orderlineitem_portal_rownum == 0) break; else  $ids_orderlineitem_portal_rownum++;
}//portal_end
.'
</SiteNameList>
</inventoryUpdateRequest>'
;
$url ='https://inventoryupdate.sitename.com';
$port = 80;

$response = xml_post($xml, $url, $port);    
?>
```

Help?  How can I get the loop to output the format I need?

Comment: Use one of the XML extensions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060346/php-what-is-the-best-approach-to-using-xml-need-to-create-and-parse-xml-response

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know if this will work, because I don't know what format the input data is in , but hopefully this should work, or is at least closer to what you need:

```
<?php 
    $xml =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
    <inventoryUpdateRequest version="1.0">
    <action name="bookupdate">
    </action>
    <SiteNameList>';
    foreach($ids_row['order_line_item::bookID'] as  $book_id)
    {
        $xml .= '
        <SiteName>
        <vendorBookID>
        '.$book_id.'
        </vendorBookID>
        </SiteName>';
    }//portal_end
    $xml .= '
    </SiteNameList>
    </inventoryUpdateRequest>'
    ;

    $url ='https://inventoryupdate.sitename.com';
    $port = 80;

    $response = xml_post($xml, $url, $port);    
?>
```

Comment: Jodes, tried your method, source code shows correct xml format and info, but response from webservice says XML error.  Grr, feels like the solution is so close!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, so I figured it out, I was missing a "?" at the end of the first line.  And so it works beautifully now.  Thank you Jodes, my hero!